# angular2 ngfor only if index is less than certain number

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm using an ngfor to display a varying amount of items. I want to limit the amount of items it can display to 5 so I use:

```
<li  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
     <div *ngIf="i < 4">
       //more stuff ...
     </div>
</li>
```

But what this does it that it seems to be rendering the space for items over index = 4.

If I try:

```
<li  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" *ngIf="i < 4"> //Notice ngIF
```

Nothing is displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:5; let i = index;">
  <div>
    //more stuff ... 
  </div>
</li>
```

Maybe that's an option that works for you.

Comment: whats the function of slice here ,could you explain bit more  ?

Comment: slice creates a new array with a subset of the elements in 'items' (in that case with the first 5 elements of 'items'). So the 'ngFor' will only see that temporary array with 5 elements. See also the documentation of [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-template

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items"  let-i="index" >
        <div *ngIf=" i < 4">
            {{item}}
        </div>
</ng-template>
```